# CSVHelper C# DateTime column is throwing String is not a valid datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper v4.0.30319.  I'm reading a CSV file that for a date has "//".  I was trying to override DefaultTypeConverter.ConvertFromString, but it is not being called. Below is my code.  How do I correctly handle this?

How do I handle this?

```
    public void Reader()
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"test.csv"))
        {
            try
            {
                var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
                reader.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateTime?>(new DateTimeConverter());

                IEnumerable<DataRecord> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord>();

                foreach (DataRecord record in records.Take(5))
                {
                    Debug.Print("{0} {1}, {2}, {3}", record.compid, record.standard, record.lastpmread,
                        record.pm_type001);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Library.WriteErrorLog(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Who/what is throwing the error?  Your Code? CSVHelper?  have you tried using the `ConvertUsing()` configuration option?

Comment: have you tried removing default converter first? `TypeConverterFactory.RemoveConverter<DateTime?>();` this problem looks similar to another question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592093/2516718

Comment: It is happening on call to reader.GetRecords()
I have not tried ConvertUsing().  Looking into how to use it  Don't know how to use it also.

Yes, it is similar, but the other question is writing, where I am reading a CSV.  

My data is:

{"S-RF13","Annual SOP Summary and Certification","Months","Static","REFRIGERATION","YEAR ROUND",8.00,0.00,01/18/2018,5528,"N/A",0.00,"PSM",  /  /    ,F,01/18/2019
}

I'm not expert C#.  Trying to create a service to read CSV file from 3rd party.

Comment: If you type is a `DateTime?` you shouldn't have to add a converter. If you need to change the format for parsing of the `DateTime`, you can do that through configuration.

Comment: Can you give a code example of setting this configuration up?  note, the DateTime column in CSV sometimes can be:  "  /  /    ", and this, I'm guess, is my problem.
btw:  I did add in RemoveConverter call, but now getting a different error which I'm trying to figure out.  Thanks for all the help!