# How can I serialize DateTime with miliseconds in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, datetime

I wat to serialize object with `DateTime` field to csv with milliseconds. How can I do this?

I'm writing csv by this code:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_checksumsFilePath))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
   csv.WriteRecords(_checksums.Values.ToList());
}
```

And `_checksums` is `Dictionary` of this class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string val{ get; set; }

    public DateTime lastTime{ get; set; }
}
```

When I write, I see from debugger - in DateTime are some miliseconds but to csv file write only:

```
Name;val;lastTime
someName;49BC20DF15E412A64472421E13FE86FF1C5165E18B2AFCCF160D4DC19FE68A14;29.05.2019 16:13:08
```

Comment: CsvPropertyMap includes a `TypeConverterOption` method to specify such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank but I make my own converter from this topic [CsvHelper set default custom TypeConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133413/csvhelper-set-default-custom-typeconverter)

I make some little changes

```
    public class DateConverter : ITypeConverter
    {
        private readonly string _dateFormat;

        public DateConverter(string dateFormat)
        {
            _dateFormat = dateFormat;
        }

        public object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                DateTime dt;
                DateTime.TryParseExact(text, _dateFormat,
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                       DateTimeStyles.None,
                                       out dt);
                if (IsValidSqlDateTime(dt))
                {
                    return dt;
                }

            }

            return null;
        }
        public string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            return ObjectToDateString(value, _dateFormat);
        }

        public string ObjectToDateString(object o, string dateFormat)
        {
            if (o == null) return string.Empty;

            DateTime dt;
            if (o is DateTime)
            {
                dt = (DateTime)o;
                return dt.ToString(dateFormat);
            }
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
        public bool IsValidSqlDateTime(DateTime? dateTime)
        {
            if (dateTime == null) return true;

            DateTime minValue = DateTime.Parse(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.ToString());
            DateTime maxValue = DateTime.Parse(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue.ToString());

            if (minValue > dateTime.Value || maxValue < dateTime.Value)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

and use :

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_checksumsFilePath))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.RemoveConverter<DateTime>();
                csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.RemoveConverter<DateTime?>();
                csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateTime?>(new DateConverter("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateTime>(new DateConverter("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                csv.WriteRecords(_checksums.Values.ToList());
            }
```

Comment: in the newest version, you have to use `csv.Context.TypeConverterCache`  instead of `csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache`

Answer (score 2):

I made an improvement to your answer by making use of the functions of the base classes.
Assuming you are only writing csv files this should do the trick.
The class `DefaultTypeConverter` ([GitHub](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/DefaultTypeConverter.cs)) gets the required format out of `memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.Formats`.
Since this parameter is set for all converters in the class `CsvWriter`, which you probably don't want, you can edit this function the way I did, to use a custom format.
This function now doesn't use a format set in the class `CsvWriter`, but uses your own format.

```
public class DateConverter : DateTimeConverter
{
    private readonly string dateFormat;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DateConverter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateFormat">Format in which the data should be formatted.</param>
    public DateConverter(string dateFormat)
        : base()
    {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            if (memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.NullValues.Count > 0)
            {
                return memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.NullValues.First();
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (value is IFormattable formattable)
        {
            var format = this.dateFormat;
            return formattable.ToString(format, memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.CultureInfo);
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this [`CsvHelper`](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), there seems to be a way to configure it with a `ClassMap`:

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration

Comment: THE problem with links in an answer.... `Http.StatusCode == 404` ... page not found.

Comment: Yeah his documentation seems to have disappeared. There's a similar question that shows how to do date formatting in a more recent version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779725/how-to-output-dates-into-csv-file-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-instead-of-dd-mm-yyyy-hh