# CsvHelper version 22.1.2 default TypeConverter for properties of a particular type

Tags: c#, csvhelper

In previous versions of CsvHelper, custom TypeConverters could be assigned to CsvConfiguration objects in a straightforward fashion, as described in the Stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592093/12328315). In version 22.1.2, it appears the TypeConverterCache is moved to the CsvContext class, but I cannot access it.

```
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
            {
                // this works to access the existing TypeConverterCache objects
                csv.Context.get_TypeConverterCache();

                // error: Property, indexer, or event 'CsvContext.TypeConverterCache' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'CsvContext.get_TypeConverterCache()' or 'CsvContext.set_TypeConverterCache(?)
                csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<bool>(new MyCustomBooleanConverter());

                // error: CsvContext.set_TypeConverterCache(?)' is not supported by the language
                csv.Context.set_TypeConverterCache(xyz);
            }
```

I am trying to set a default converter for all Boolean fields. I can see the TypeConverterCache property is a public field on CsvContext in the source code so I'm unsure what I am doing wrong.

`public virtual TypeConverterCache TypeConverterCache { get; set; }`

Does anyone have any insight into the best approach for setting a default TyperConverter for a particular data type in CsvHelper 22.1.2?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work just fine using .NET 5 as per [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TKVVm1). I'm not quite sure which C# version dotnetfiddle uses, but I'd expect the latest (9.0) when using .NET 5.

However, in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I79cXS) using .NET Framework 4.7.2 I can reproduce your error. My guess is C# v7.3 is used, but that's just a guess.

So one solution for you might be to upgrade to a newer version of C#. Alternatively I'd suggest you create an issue on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues) to see if it's intended in case the author doesn't follow the SO tag here.